# C# How to get the current Page Coded UI TEST in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I want to know if it's possible to get / know the current page in wpf.

In my project, I put this code and I have the correct page:

```
var current_page = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content.GetType();
```

Windows.Current.Content was null.

But in my UI Test project, I have the following error:

> Result Message:
>   Test method CodedUITestProject1.CodedUiTest.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I don't know C#, but does it let you define variables with a space in the name?

Comment: No, i just forget an underscore.

Comment: Getting and testing the page isn't a good idea. Can you instead move the code you want to test into a different class, and unit-test it there?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page

Comment: if i move the code, its will be the same. Its a Coded Unit Test.
the unit test making the UI thread

Comment: @MethodMan what is wrong?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the issue is .. you need to declare as well as create an instance of an object. did you use the the debugger to step through your code.. .?

Comment: @MethodMan Ok but its not help me a lot

Comment: do you know how to use the Debugger..?

Comment: Not a lot, just use to know the value.